# OpenID Plug-ins

Tags: openid

I am starting a website up now and I maybe using WordPress but if I use static HTML is there a way I can use OpenID on my site.

I now about the Apache module but I have a simply hosting plan with GoDaddy that has PHP and I was wondering is there any other OpenID plug-ins.

I know about delgation but I don't really won't to use that because I want to contorl the features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched on google and found an [exhaustive list of openID libraries](http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995176/Libraries), you can select one of the php one which provides all functionalities you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the WP plug-in that has an advance feature set and you can choose who has the main domain and choos the users how can use it.